# What exactly does the ReCommit feature in TortoiseGit do?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I recently updated git and TortoiseGit and when I wanted to do my next commit I noticed a new feature called `ReCommit`. Being curious as I am, I just clicked on it. Now it seems to have done a regular commit and reopened the refreshed commit dialog, but the console/log window immediately disappeared so I couldn't see what was going on in the background.

Unfortunately the [TortoiseGit doc](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/) doesn't include any hints on this.

Is `ReCommit` really just `commit and reopen commit dialog` or is there more to this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It really is just "commit and leave the commit dialog open." Based on the discussion here: https://tortoisegit.org/issue/527

Also see the official documentation: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-commit.html

Comment: Thanks, and +1 for the reference